# Can two synchronous clients use same request/reply topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a User service which is listening to a request topic and returning the User object.  I need to call this service synchronously from two different services and wanted to confirm if its ok for them to use the same request/response topic names to both request the User object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template).

There are two options when using the same reply topic:

1. Discard unexpected replies:

> When configuring with a single reply topic, each instance must use a different group.id. In this case, all instances receive each reply, but only the instance that sent the request finds the correlation ID. This may be useful for auto-scaling, but with the overhead of additional network traffic and the small cost of discarding each unwanted reply. When you use this setting, we recommend that you set the template’s `sharedReplyTopic` to true, which reduces the logging level of unexpected replies to DEBUG instead of the default ERROR.

2. Use dedicated partitions:

> If you have multiple client instances and you do not configure them as discussed in the preceding paragraph, each instance needs a dedicated reply topic. An alternative is to set the `KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION` and use a dedicated partition for each instance. The Header contains a four-byte int (big-endian). The server must use this header to route the reply to the correct partition (`@KafkaListener` does this). In this case, though, the reply container must not use Kafka’s group management feature and must be configured to listen on a fixed partition (by using a `TopicPartitionOffset` in its `ContainerProperties` constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple consumers can read and process same message from same topic if both consumers are in different consumer group.